# SQL UPDATE using unusual syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I came across this stored procedure today and I'm confused with the syntax on it. It is doing an UPDATE and the query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @TransactionStatus tinyint = 1, 
        @RedeemedAmount decimal(18,2) = 0, 
        @PromotionCodeAmount decimal(18,2) = 0,
        @EventDetailId int = 0

UPDATE PED
    SET @RedeemedAmount = PED.RedeemedAmount = PED.RedeemedAmount + PE.PromoCodeAmount, 
        @PromotionCodeAmount = PE.PromoCodeAmount,   
        @EventDetailId = PED.Id
FROM dbo.PromotionEvents AS PE 
JOIN dbo.PromotionEventDetails AS PED ON PED.EventId = PE.Id
    WHERE PED.Id IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 PED.ID
        FROM dbo.PromotionEvents AS PE 
        JOIN dbo.PromotionEventDetails AS PED ON PED.EventId = PE.Id
        WHERE PE.Id = @EventId
    AND PED.Amount >= PED.RedeemedAmount + PE.PromoCodeAmount 
        AND PE.StartDate <= GETDATE() AND PE.EndDate > GETDATE()
        AND PE.MStatusId = 1
        AND PED.MStatusId = 1
        ORDER BY PED.CreatedDateTime)
```

This is only a portion of the whole stored procedure. I just need to understand what this part does?

```
SET @RedeemedAmount = PED.RedeemedAmount = PED.RedeemedAmount + PE.PromoCodeAmount,
```

Notice that there are two equals signs on that line.

Comment: This is just some algebra, adding three decimals together and storing that result to another decimal.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen did you notice there is `=` not `+` between the decimals, i.e. two `=` signs on the line not two `+` signs?

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen. Thanks for the prompt reply. I had the same thought too but when i googled, I just couldn't find any reference to this. Do you happen to have one?

Comment: @JiriTousek I missed that.  I've never seen this in SQL.  In Java, yes, but not in SQL.

Comment: This technique is a bit odd to say the least and there are very important caveats to this working correctly. It is known as the "quirky update". Jeff Moden has a great article on the topic here and how to use this for a running total. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line does two things at once:

- Updates the `PromotionEventDetails.RedeemedAmount` column
- Stores the same value in `@RedeemedAmount` variable

This seems to be a mix of usual `UPDATE ... SET column = expression` with SQL Server's "set variable" syntax of `SET @variable = expression`. Tests show it is impossible to do `@a = @b = col1` or `col1 = col2 = col3`, it only works for one variable and one target column.

Comment: As for these 2 lines, i guess they are just setting up the variable aren't they?
`@PromotionCodeAmount = PE.PromoCodeAmount,   
@EventDetailId = PED.Id`